# Round or sharp separation edges for lower drag?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag

Two same object,only difference is in separation edges,one has round ,other has sharp edges.

Round edges decrease wake but edges itslef produce low pressure because of curvature.

Sharp edges increase wake but dont produce low pressure like round edges.

Which type of edges is better for lower drag? Object is 5m long..

[image]

Comment: Do they really?  The trend seems to be towards rounding the trailing edges, but it may have much to to with velocity of the airstream over the surface and where the turbulence begins.  It seems (in wind tunnel tests) that the shape of the airflow can matter is much as the shape of the object.

Comment: Well they don't always use sharp edges, but whenever possible they do.

Comment: It might be a weight/parking clearance best compromise, but the Wrights(with their wind tunnel) seemed to like a little rounding at the trailing edge tips.

Comment: Which size are you talking about 10cm, 20m? What is the section?

Comment: Don't say it is a car, this is **Aviation** Stack Exchange 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The car industry uses the shapes they do for a reason. A clean separation with sharp edges as presented in the picture produces less drag than letting the airflow follow a conture that turns it drastically.

In aviation it is preferred to use fairings to "strech shapes that would otherwise present the dilemma mentioned in your question. Therefore this is not that much of an actual consideration in  aircraft design.

These fairings transform the shapes such, that the radius of the terminating shape is in the order of magnitude of centimeter (fuselage, engine pods and such) or millimeters (wings, flaps, ailerons etc.). In these scales the sharpness may present more problems than advantages, mainly from manufacturing point of view: for example for aluminium construction sharp edges are not desirable, as they are structurally prone to failure.